# Spring tool suite: missing "package name" option

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have STS v3.6.3 installed on Windows 7 and creating a new "Spring Starter Project" the option "package name" doesn't appear, so the default "demo" package is created.
I've read on the STS issuetracker website about this and they say that it has been fixed in the 3.6.4 version, but it is not yet available for download.
How could I fix this while they publish the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Spring-IDE component from STS from a nightly build update site: http://dist.springframework.org/snapshot/IDE/nightly/